# Roots of a cubic polynomial in $[-1,1]$

Tags: polynomials, roots, cubics

I am preparing for an entrance and this question has taken too much of my time.

> Suppose function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is given by $$f(x) = x^3 - 3x + b$$ Find the number of points in the closed interval $[-1,1]$ at which $f(x)=0$.

How to find the number of roots of $f$? I have found the roots of $f'$ are $\pm 1$.  Its a MCQ and answer says atmost one but mine is coming to be 2. I wanted to see how derivative can help in finding roots of a polynomial

Comment: Your issue is equivalent to find the abscissas of intersection(s) points of the curve $y=x^3-3x$ (that we advise you to study though the sign of its derivative, and draw) and the horizontal line $y=-b$.

Comment: Also, please study [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619). This looks too much like an attempt to outsource homework.

Comment: 1 question in 3 months is not an attempt to outsource homework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

As $f'(x)=3(x^2-1)<0$ on $(-1,1)$, $f(x)$ is decreasing on $[-1,1]$, hence it has at most one root on this interval.

It has exactly one root if and only if $f(1)$ and $f(-1)$ have opposite signs. This will depend on the value of $b$.

Comment: This is, in my opinion, way too substantial to be called a hint.

Comment: @Arthur.: I agree, but it isn't so easy in this case  to indicate the right direction. Is the new version better, for you?

Comment: I wasn't really saying that your answer was bad (it wasn't). Only that putting "hint" at the top was a bit of a stretch. And yes, some times it's difficult to find a good spot between "completely useless" and "basically a full answer"

Comment: Thanks bernard for the hint (actually more than a hint!).